# Mac timer app that show a full screen dialog box at specified intervals

Tags: macos, timer

I am looking for an interval timer app that show a full screen dialog box at specified intervals.

With the following requirements:
for macOS 10.13.6
open source if possible, free at the very least. If not possible at all, dun mind paid options

Features needed:
User must be able to set the dialog box to appear full screen covering the whole desktop, so the user cannot ignore the dialog box and must click on a button on it to exit
If the com is asleep, there won't be an accumulation of dialog boxes during the time the com is asleep